# Disabling strange emacs comment highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, scheme

I have started programming scheme, and I noticed the scheme minor mode highlights comments in the most obnoxious way possible when using solarized dark (color-theme-solarized). This also occurs on elisp files. Its a super bright grey, and makes the contrast too much to handle. I suppose its because the solarized theme overwrote some color that would normally be used for this kind of thing.

Is there a way I can disable highlighting of these comments or correct the color? It's making the code unreadable, and Google is not helping. This seems to only occur on lisp-likes, such as scheme and elisp on my Arch Linux machine. On my mac, this does not occur.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the above answer from PuercoPop I ended up finding the problem, and it was unrelated to `font-comment-lock-face`. For reference I am running solarized in both my terminal, and in Emacs.

I run Arch Linux with URxvt. I noticed I could "fake" rxvt by adding `URxvt*termName: rxvt` to my Xresources file. This worked, except for when I used tmux, or most anything else.

The real solution was two-fold

First, I set my `TERM` equal to `rxvt-256color` and then made a simlink of `/usr/share/terminfo/r/rxvt-256color` to `~/.terminfo/r/rvxt-256color`.

This smoothed out the color weirdness involved. Emacs correctly adjusted the colors for my terminal. PuercoPop's solution works in general if your colors are wrong, but not if Emacs isn't cooperating with your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The face in question is `font-lock-comment-face`, just [change the color](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Face-Customization.html) to something more to your liking.

In general, when one wants to figure out what properties are being applied to a string, one can go to the character in question and <kbd>M-x</kbd> `describe-char`.